# Striping of results from MySQL UNION

Tags: mysql, union

I am trying to conceptualize how to set up UNION of 3 tables that will allow for ordering in a striping fashion.

Top 5 from the UNION of Tables A,B,C
with results ordered like so:

A
B
C
A
B
C
....

Is this sort of thing possibe with SQL and more specifically MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would pull the three queries out separately, and then process through them in your favourite programming language. The queries should run faster like this, as they would not be so complex.

It should be possible using only SQL though, by adding a couple of columns to your output for each of the three queries, and then wrapping the whole lot in an outer select such as;

```
SELECT * FROM ( <PUT THE FULL UNION HERE> ) ORDER BY table_name, row_count
```

You'd need to alter each of the queries like this;

```
@@rowCount=0;
SELECT 'A' AS table_name, (@@rowCount+1) AS row_count, <remaining fields>
FROM table_A;
```

Now, I'm not totally sure of the syntax for the incrementing row counter, but I've seen it done elsewhere (probably on StackOverflow somewhere), so maybe someone else can help with that part? (Or you may find the answer by searching this site...)

Comment: Oh yeah, duh. Pull records from each assigning row number, then group by row number and a table designator.  I'll do some more spelunking of SO for the rowCount assignment.

Comment: If you find a good working solution for the rowCount thingumy, update your question, or post here as a comment to my answer and I'll update the answer to include the correct syntax.

Comment: Maybe I jumped too soon on the answer check.  This gets me almost there.  It does not reset rowCount though so you get a single set of incremental ranking values. 

    `SELECT * FROM ( 

    SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ranking,
    'A' AS t_name    
FROM tableA t
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r; 

UNION

SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ranking,
'B' AS t_name    
FROM tableB t2
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r2;

) AS t3 GROUP BY ranking`

Comment: Ok, so what about using three separate variable names for the individual queries, and then when they are SELECTed AS a particular field name you can sort by that field? I'm not sure your "GROUP BY" will do what you need though, I'm sure you need to use "ORDER BY"?

Comment: You earned that one.  Thanks a million.  Here is the working SQL:

    `SELECT * FROM 
( 

SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ranking, 
'A' AS t_name 
FROM tableA t JOIN 
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r 

UNION 

SELECT @rownumB := @rownumB + 1 AS ranking,
'B' AS t_name FROM tableB t2 
JOIN (SELECT @rownumB := 0) r2 
) 

AS t3 ORDER BY ranking, t_name`

Comment: No probs, glad to be of some help :)